# \textasteriskcentered invisible with [garamond]{mathdesign}

Tags: fonts, symbols, sans-serif, mathdesign

Please try this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{roboto} % or another sans serif font, e.g. the cabin package
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
Centred asterisk \textasteriskcentered, which is different from this one: *.
\end{document}
```

Different LaTeX installations I use compile this without the `\textasteriskcentered`, i.e. invisible. What is causing this and how could this be fixed? Note that you need to add the .pfb files from URW-Garamond to your path. If you disable the sans serif package, you get a `\textasteriskcentered` in a different (the default?) font than Garamond. Does this mean the .pfb files from URW-Garamond aren't the ones I need? Also, I wonder what other glyphs aren't showing up correctly. How do I use Garamond with `mathdesign` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple: the font the glyph corresponding to `\textasteriskcentered` should be taken from lacks the character; this is witnessed by the line

```
Missing character: There is no * in font mdugmr8c!
```

You need to supply it in some other way, for example by lowering the standard asterisk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{roboto} % or another sans serif font, e.g. the cabin package
\usepackage{blindtext}

% remove the definition of \textasteriskcentered for TS1 encoding
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{TS1}
% reinstate a default encoding
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}
% suitably define the command
\DeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}{\raisebox{-.7ex}[1ex][0pt]{*}}

\begin{document}

Centred asterisk \textasteriskcentered, which is different from this one: *.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you! How do you know the values to raise (or lower) the box: Is it just trial and error, do you know the value, or is it deducible? I believe the `ex` length is directly proportional to font size, so this solution works for any font size setting.

Comment: @Erik I did some experiments, this one seemed best.

Comment: To me `-.7ex` seems good too: the asterisk looks very nicely centred in `x\textasteriskcentered x` (between two x's), although the default font has a centred asterisk that seems bigger and raised a little higher. I'll adjust manually if the asterisk seems out of place in a footnote symbol next to other footnote symbols. By the way: why do you specify the height and depth of the `\raisebox`? If I set them to different values, nothing happens? And I can omit them too, nothing happens as well.