# Making a ruled dinkus

Tags: line

How can I make a `ruled dinkus` in `LaTeX`?   Meaning three asterisks `***` with a short line (or extending to the paragraph width) on either side of `***`.

Comment: Take a look at this question for some inspiration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160336/asterism-and-similar-breaking-non-breaking-options

Comment: The difficulty is that I want a line at each end.

Comment: Use `\rule{<width>}{<thickness>}` and put the whole thing in a `\centerline{}`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with. A command with one optional parameter, the width of the whole dinkus as a proporition of `\linewidth`, where the default is `1` (full width of the line).

[image: dinkus]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233857
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{TS1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textasteriskcentered}{OT1}{\raisebox{-.7ex}[1ex][0pt]{*}}

\newcommand{\dinkus}[1][1]{%
  \par\vskip0.5\baselineskip%
  \noindent%
  \hbox to \dimexpr 0.5\linewidth - #1\linewidth / 2\relax{}%
  \xrfill[0.5ex]{0.4pt}%
  \;\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\;%
  \xrfill[0.5ex]{0.4pt}%
  \hbox to \dimexpr 0.5\linewidth - #1\linewidth / 2\relax{}%
  \vskip0.5\baselineskip\par}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\dinkus[0.2]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Despite my earlier comment, using `\centerline` in LaTeX is a bad idea according to various TeX.SE answers.

I used the `xhfill` package for the rules (otherwise difficult to get a raised `\hrulefill`), and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233857) to get an asterisk that should be centered vertically on the line for different fonts. You may have to play with the height of the rule (hard-coded to `0.5ex`) to get it perfectly aligned with the asterisks for some fonts. MinionPro didn't look perfect, but everything else I tried did. I don't know if you can make it totally foolproof.